# call WSDL by PHP

Tags: php

I need to use an WSDL, and call some functions. I need my request will have this format:

username
password

I can not get any data back from server, the server can not recognize my transfer parameters.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Please add some code. Explain what SOAP-extension or library you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the web service, which is described be your WSDL, try something like this:

```
class myWebServiceParameter {
    public $username = "me";
    public $password = "secret";
}

try{
    $client = new SoapClient("http://example.org/myWebService.wsdl",
        array('location' =>"http://example.org/myWebServiceEndpoint"));
    $parameter1 = new myWebServiceParameter();
    $result = $client->myWebServiceFunction($parameter1);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // handle errors
}
```

myWebServiceParameter must be any class with a member variable foreach WSDL message attribute of the same name. And myWebServiceFunction is the name of the web service method.

Comment: Sorry for posting lacking information, but i added one item more for my question, could you see it on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723160/call-wsdl-by-php. Many thanks.